# Electron how to use a method that's not in the main.js file

Tags: electron

I have an electron project that looks like this:

```
index.html
main.js
edit.js
package.json
etc...
```

In edit.js I have a function:

```
myfunction() {
    // do something
}
```

In main.js I have a Menu and from that menu I want to use the function that's in edit...

Like this:

```
{
label:'MenuItem1',
click() {
  myfunction(); // This function is not here in main.js but in edit.js
 }
},
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export the function you want to use in main.js and require the `edit.js` file:

**edit.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    myfunction: function () {
        // do something here...
    }
};
```

or

```js
exports.myfunction = function() {
    // do something here...
}
```

---

**main.js**

```js
const { MenuItem } = require('electron');
const { myfunction } = require(__dirname + '/edit.js');

// Now myfunction is accessible in main.js
// ...

const menuItem = new MenuItem({
    label: 'MenuItem1',
    click: function() {
        myfunction();
    },
    // ...
});

// OR

const menuItem2 = new MenuItem({
    label: 'MenuItem2',
    click: myfunction,
    // ...
});
```

Comment: For some reason I keep getting this error when I build: Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'. ... any ideas why?